# pthread_cond_timedwait return immediately after sometimes in freeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have a loop that monitor things and I use pthread_cond_timedwait for blocking.
It will run every 10 secs at first, but when it throw error 22 (Invalid argument) it keeps running without waiting.
EINVAL means my abstime is wrong [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html][1].
Below is my code

```
 while (!getStopFlag()) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&monitor_lock);
            gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
            time_t sec = now.tv_sec + updateSec;
            long nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
            sec += nsec / 1000000000L;
            nsec = nsec % 1000000000L;
            outtime.tv_sec = sec;
            outtime.tv_nsec = 0;
            ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&monitor_condition, &monitor_lock, &outtime);

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&monitor_lock);
    }
```

Don't know why it's OK at first few times and fail after.
I also try

```
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
        now.tv_sec += updateSec;
        ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&monitor_condition, &monitor_lock, &now);
```

and

```
outtime.tv_sec = time(0) + updateSec;
        outtime.tv_nsec = 0;
        ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&monitor_condition, &monitor_lock, &outtime);
```

Comment: found the solution by myself, change clock type to  CLOCK_MONOTONIC then solve.